# Hambuger Menu - CSS Transition - two directions?

Tags: html, css, web, css-selectors, frontend

I've successfully implemented a hamburger menu animation using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and it currently operates smoothly in one direction. How can I ensure that it works seamlessly in the other direction as well? Also, could you please review my code to check for any improvements or optimizations?

I tried to add transition class on the  .menu.open .line* but it doesn't work in reverse it interferes with first transaction.

```js
const menu_button = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0];
const menu_info = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-info')[0];
let menu_open = false;

menu_button.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(){
    if(menu_open == false){
        menu_button.classList.remove("close");
        menu_button.classList.add("open");
        menu_info.classList.add("animation");
        menu_open = true;
    } else{
        menu_button.classList.remove("open");
        menu_button.classList.add("close");
        menu_info.classList.remove("animation");
        menu_open = false;
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1vw;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
/* navbar setup start */
nav{
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1001;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/* navbar setup end */

/* menu icon setup start*/

.menu{
    width: 30px;
    height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
}

.menu .line1, .menu.close .line1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    rotate: 0deg;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition-property: top, width, rotate, transform;
    transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.1s, 0.1s, 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s, 0.3s, 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}


.menu .line2, .menu.close .line2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    width: 100%;
    rotate: 0deg;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition-property: top, width, rotate, transform;
    transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.1s, 0.1s, 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s, 0.3s, 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.menu .line3, .menu.close .line3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    rotate: 0deg;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition-property: top, width, rotate, transform;
    transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.1s, 0.1s, 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s, 0.3s, 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu.open .line1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    width: 10%;
    rotate: 45deg;
    transform: scaleX(10);
}

.menu.open .line2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    width: 10%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}

.menu.open .line3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    width: 10%;
    rotate: -45deg;
    transform: scaleX(10);
}

.menu.close .line {
    
}

.menu.close .line1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    transition: all 500ms;
}

.menu.close .line2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    transition: all 500ms;
}

.menu.close .line3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    transition: all 500ms;
}

/* menu icon setup end*/

/* menu setup start*/
.menu-info{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    display: none;
}

.menu-info.animation{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.kraftit-color{
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu-links{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color: white;
}

/* menu setup start*/
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo-section">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="line line1"></div>
    <div class="line line2"></div>
    <div class="line line3"></div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="menu-info">
  <div class="menu-links">
    <div class="link"><h1>About</h1></div>
    <div class="link"><h1>About</h1></div>
    <div class="link"><h1>About</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="kraftit-color"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have created a snippet from your code, but when I run it, there is no obvious problem. The only animation I can see is on the menu button ... did you intend for there to be additional animations? You may need to edit your question (and/or the snippet) to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: The problem was in the hamburger menu the return animation was not good. But I fixed it. Thanx for the answer anyway.

Comment: the problem was that I didn't use transition in both added classes (open) and (close) the right way I switched them and that's why it didn't work right in the return